# How to store JavaScript variable value in JSP session

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to store a JavaScript variable value in JSP session to use it further in my Java classes methods. Please provide solution for storing any JavaScript variable in JSP session.

Answer (score 1):

Pass that variable to Servlet using ajax OR set it in some hidden field when form will get submit it will also get POSTed.

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX call from your JSP to a different JSP that does that. The jsp will take a variable name and its value as request parameters and will put the variable in the session.

You cannot do this with client side (javascript) code only !

Comment: “You cannot do this with client side (javascript) code only!” But you could use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

Comment: Aren't these HTML 5 features ? Maybe you could use them, but I would like to have a fallback mechanism in case my browser didn't support 'em...

Comment: You could fall back to cookies for IE7 and older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just store the value in a cookie. Both client side javascript and server side jsp can access cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a natural flow to your program, so that you don't have to have a mechanism specifically for storing variables just for the sake of storing variables.  By that I mean that if you are storing a userName, it should be while login is occurring, or if you are obtaining contactInfo, then you should have a servlet specifically for that purpose.  Regardless, here is a three part answer to your question.  It is very general and non-specific, but will accomplish what you want once fleshed out:

Here is the web.xml file:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StoreVariableServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>tests.servlets.StoreVariableServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StoreVariableServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/storeVariableServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the jQuery Code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/storeVariableServlet",
        data: ({
            variable : $(variableName).val()
        }),
        success: function(){
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
```

Here is the Servlet Code:

```
    String variableToBeStored = request.getParameter("variable");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("variableXYZ", variableToBeStored);
```